# JAR File causing "Could not find or load main class" when using JavaFX

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I've dealing with this for 1 week already and I didn't find any valid solutions. I'm using `JavaFX` to run a WebBrowser in an application. Everything works fine when running it from the IDE (IntellijIDEA). The problem comes when I export to a JAR file and I try to execute it. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I'm currently using/tried:

- Java SDK 1.8 which already contains JavaFX library
- Java SDK 12 adding JavaFX as an external library
- JRE 8
- JRE 12
- Windows 10 x64

This is my manifest file:

[image]

And this is my project structure:

[image]

These are my JAR (Artifact) settings:

[image]

I can't find a way to get it working. Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add `--add-modules javafx.controls` to the VM Options?

Comment: @trilogy SDK 1.8 is not modular. Btw, tried in SDK 12 and not working :/

Comment: I had the same issue but got past it, but trying to remember what I did (at least for 12; 8 I had no issues)...

Comment: @trilogy I appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Now I remember, the problem was it was missing dependencies. NetBeans had a bug that it wouldn't save the dependencies in the "dist/lib" folder. Weird thing is, that if you comment out the contents in your "public void Start(Stage)" method, it would work fine. As soon as you reference a dependency, that error would show up....

Comment: I found something. I added a new Run/Debug configuration in IntellijIDEA targetted to the JAR file and it surprisingly ran. The command shown in console is the following: `D:\Workspace\_Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar D:\Workspace\IntellijIDEA\myproject\out\artifacts\myproject_jar\myproject.jar`. I removed the encoding argument and it still runs. But then I removed the absolute path to the JDK I got the error. When the JAR runs, an exception is thrown when the program reached a File open function. It looks like it's all related to paths.